# Why column of table so wide?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm backend developer and have `spring boot` project with template engine `thymeleaf`.
I have table. Last column has 3 icons-hyperlinks.
My css style:

```
td.last {
            width: 1px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

My html:

```
 <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
                <th>Column3</th>
                <th>Column4</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">Column5</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            ...
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Foo</td>
                <td>Bar</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="link1?id=9" class="create-confirm" data-target="#dlgCreate" role="button" data-title="Foo bar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    <span>41</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="display:inline-block;">
                        <a href="details?id=9"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                        <a href="#" class="delete-confirm" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dlgDelete" data-title="Delete FooBar" data-method="delete?id=9"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                        <a style="display: null" href="/link2?param1=FooBar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>            
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Why my last column so wide?
[image]

Comment: We need a [mcve]. With one CSS rule and a couple of images we can't possibly begin to do anything other than hazard guesses.

Comment: Try width: 1px !important;

Comment: @j08691, sorry, I updated the post.

Comment: @patrik-rikama-hinnenberg, thanks, but did not help.

Comment: So the template/framework is probably creating some own root styles that you should be able to override if targeting on right classnames it is generating.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing classname `last` on your td.. I think you might mean `:last-child`. Change your `td.last` css style to below one..

```
td:last-child{
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

See the Snippet below:

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
}
td:last-child{
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Number</td>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td>Action</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>James</td>
  <td>1212121</td>
  <td>USA</td>
  <td>Edit Delete Graph</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/ja1L3yqt/) also.

Comment: Wait, your last column is reduced.

Comment: As per your css in `td.last` it should be `1px` and still its not making it `1px`.. In my solution I made it `20px` so you can see the output, if you want to show everything in `td` with `20px` of width then just remove `overflow: hidden` from the style..